# Using on newer Android Studio old library (or apply effect on text in another way) to do "Star Wars" credits style

Tags: android, text, windows-10, effects

I have a newer project on Android Studio (Windows 10) that consists in a "Vader Says" inspired in "Simon Says" (Star Wars version).
I have a class that manages scores and does a credits effect moving lines from bottom to top. I have been searching a way to apply the Star Wars credits that moves smaller to horizon and I only found "CreditsRoll" that have about 8 years old so it's impossible to upgrade and use lot of deprecated stuff with the actual gradle. You can check the library here:

https://github.com/frakbot/CreditsRoll

If you need something of my code I'll pleasantly share it.

Any idea of how do the effect if this library or project is too old to apply it on my project?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

PS: I searched a lot in Google before asking, even tried another similar post solutions, but upgrading it's impossible as far as I know (tried commands throw cmd to upgrade but failed due too many deprecated things).

**Code for the Scoreboard and the Layout**

```
------CLASS-------

package org.proven.dnf_vader_says;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ScoreBoard extends AppCompatActivity{


    TextView scoreboard, title;
    int scoreBoardSound;
    private SoundPool soundPool;
    private static final String FILENAME = "scoreboard.txt";
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.scoreboard);
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.thronethemescore);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        instantiateElements();
        setElementsToListener();
        readFile();
    }

    private void setElementsToListener() {
        scoreboard.setOnClickListener(listener);
        title.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    private void instantiateElements() {

        scoreboard = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pointslist);
        scoreboard.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

    }

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.pointslist:
                    screenTapped(v);
                    break;
                case R.id.title:
                    screenTapped(v);
                    break;
                default:
                    screenTapped(v);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    public void screenTapped(View view){
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        Intent backmain = new Intent(ScoreBoard.this, VaderSaysActivity.class);
        startActivity(backmain);
    }

    private void readFile(){
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try{
            fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String scoreline;
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((scoreline = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                strBuilder.append(scoreline).append("\n");
            }
            Animation translatebu = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animationfile);
            scoreboard.setText(strBuilder);
            scoreboard.startAnimation(translatebu);
            scoreboard.setText(strBuilder);
            Spannable span = new SpannableString(scoreboard.getText());
            span.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 100, 0, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            scoreboard.setText(span);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(fis != null){
                try{
                    fis.close();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

------LAYOUT-------


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bkgrscoreboard"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
    android:onClick="screenTapped">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/jedifont"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:textColor="#d5d900"
        android:text="tabla de puntuaciones" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:src="@drawable/linesaber" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pointslist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:fontFamily="@font/jedifont"
        android:textColor="#fffda6"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried with simple `AnimationSet`s? It just resizes and moves upwards, no?

Comment: @Shark Thanks for answering. I only got to move as normal credits (bottom to top) with Animation and Spannable classes, but Star Wars credits doesn't just do text smaller as more up it is, it also needs to be skewed and no idea of how do it...

Comment: How about drawing the text on a `Canvas` then skewing that whole thing / bitmap?

Comment: @Shark But how I update the score on a canvas and how to scroll the text on it then? It will be a static image, or I missunderstood something?

Comment: You misunderstood. Once you draw the text on the canvas, you apply the initial transofmation (stretch and skew it) -  as time passes, some class (e.g. the CreditsView itself) applies more transformation to it - moves the current stuff upwards and inserts new text if there's room.

However, now that we're getting into "the meat" - what is actually stopping you from just using [his view](https://github.com/frakbot/CreditsRoll/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/net/frakbot/creditsroll/CreditsRollView.java) and be done with it?

Comment: I looked over the code, and see nothing that needs significant patching/porting to make it work on newer androids. Like, somewhere between "very little" to "nothing". Just start by porting it to androidx, and move from there.

Comment: I tried to open it on latest version of Android Studio and I was unable to make it work. I tried to install the gradle it uses and was unable to make it work with actual gradle. Let me check later the exact error and I'll post it here.
About the canvas, I don't know how to do the transformation you say, I think TextView can't be skewed as Star Wars' shape, but I'll try it too. I'll also share the code of that part.
Thanks a lot again for your time, and sorry for my ignorance, I'm still very new as you see.

Comment: The problem with CreditsRoll library is with the gradle. If I download the required one, it says it can't be upgraded until actual gradle. Then I have also problems with the import of the library. I am unable to do it properly, it is never detected.
I shared already the code for the Scoreboard. It also needs to be updated every time a new score enters to order it with the highest scores on the top, but it is secondary, my priority now is to apply the effect mentioned to the lines of the scoreboard.
Thanks again.

Comment: Hello. I've had some busy months finishing my studies. Now that I have some time to relax until I'll find my first job want to retake this project.

I've tried the things you told me but without success. @Shark did you told me you've used the library I provided (CreditsRoll) without problems? How did you do it? I am unable to make it work in the last version of Android Studio. If I could, that would be the end of my problems. May you explain a bit? Thanks so much again.

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: @Shark and everyone,

Sorry for the delay, I've had helath and familiar problems and didn't noticed the notification. As this is limited by number of characters I wrote it as an answer to see if you can keep helping.